# Convert opacity on text to hex color in sketch

Tags: css, sketch-3

Often I get a sketch file where a designer put the opacity on a colored text. This in itself isn't that awful thing, since I can just use `rgba` for color on my text in css.

But the problem is that this is a taxing function, and there really is no need for text to be opaque unless there is an image underneath it.

I can use a tool like http://marcodiiga.github.io/rgba-to-rgb-conversion

But I'd like to instruct the designers not to do that in the future. Now, knowing them, they probably won't use the above link, so I was wondering if there is a way in sketch to set the opacity of the text and just 'convert' it to rgb or hex color, depending on the background?

This would make my job a bit faster and easier :)

Is there a functionality like that in sketch?

Answer (score 1):

normally #AARRGGBB is used for hex color with opacity. When you set AA to FF its fully opaque. But in some applications there may be a control that restricts number of digits when you enter hex color (probably there is one and limited to 6).

Comment: Yeah, but if they set the text to white with 60% opacity, in rgba that will be `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)`, and the full color will depend on the background...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything easier than using a color picker to sample the value of the rasterized pixel. I use [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/designer/) but there are many other options out there.